# program context from perf sample event

Tags: kernel, perf

I am using perf_event utility to collect PEBS sample in kernel space. How can I get context information (interrupt/nmi context, program context) from perf_sample_data? I can see that perf_regs contains register informations. Which register bits indicate context of the sample?

**Update:**

I am using perf_event_open from userspace and modifying kernel in the perf event handler. I am configuring perf_event with following attribute (mem trans retired) for Intel Broadwel machine.

```
struct perf_event_attr pe = {
        .type                   = PERF_TYPE_RAW,
        .size                   = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr),
        .sample_period          = 10003,
        .sample_type            = PEBS_SAMPLE_TYPE,
        .exclude_user           = 1,
        .exclude_kernel         = 0,
        .exclude_hv             = 0,
        .disabled               = 0, 
        .config                 = 0x1cd,
        .config1                = 0x3,
        .precise_ip             = 3,
        .exclude_callchain_kernel = 0,
        .read_format            = PERF_FORMAT_GROUP | PERF_FORMAT_ID,
        .task                   = 1,
    };
    perf_event_open(&pe, processId, -1, -1 /*group*/, 0);
```

In the kernel space perf event handler, I have perf_sample_data on each sample event. How can I know whether the sample was taken from interrupt handler or the sample was from process context?

Comment: Can you clarify: Are you using `perf_event_open` from userspace or are you modifying the kernel? Please give a specific example of what events you are using  and what context you need. A [mcve] of what you have so far would go along way.

Comment: @Zulan, I have updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are modifying the kernel rather than reading the data in userspace? Is `PEBS_SAMPLE_TYPE` something you are adding?

Comment: I have defined PEBS_SAMPLE_TYPE as 

#define PEBS_SAMPLE_TYPE PERF_SAMPLE_IP | PERF_SAMPLE_TID | PERF_SAMPLE_ADDR | PERF_SAMPLE_CALLCHAIN.

Yes, I am doing some experiments in kernel space. Is it possible to know the sample context even in user-space? @Zulan

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Unfortunately I don't know the answer.

Comment: I do not think it will be possible to know the context, however if you can look at the RIP at which the PEBS enabled counter overflows (PEBS being precise will tell you exactly where the counter overflowed), and determine the context from there maybe it will help.